# Codeblocks vs GCC different output (strange behavior)?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks

I was trying to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735839/sorting-dynamic-array-in-a-structure-with-c-qsort) and after writing this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int M =10;
int N =30;
int K = 10;

struct element {
    int *i;
    int *j;
    int k;
};

struct element *create_structure();
void print_element(struct element *);
int compare (const void *, const void * );
void sort(struct element *); // changed the return value of sort
// to void as the argument will be changed directly because it is a
// pointer


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    struct element *lista;
    lista=create_structure();
    printf("\n--------- i ---  j  ---------\n\n");
    print_element(lista);
    printf("\n---------------------------\n");

    sort(lista);
    print_element(lista);
    return 0;

}


struct element *create_structure()
{
    int aux1=0,count=0;
    struct element *structure;
    // Changed the allocation of structure pointer
    structure = (struct element *) malloc (sizeof(struct element));
    structure->k=K;
    structure->i= (int *)malloc(K*sizeof(int));
    structure->j=(int *)malloc (K*sizeof(int));
    for (count = 0; count < K; count ++)
    {
        aux1=rand()%N;
        // we kept only the first aux1 and copied it in the two arrays
        (structure->i)[count]=aux1;
        (structure->j)[count]=aux1;
    }
    return (structure);
}

void print_element(struct element *lista)
{
    int count=0;
    for(count = 0; count < K; count++)
    {
        printf("row=%2d :  %2d     %2d\n",count+1,(lista->i)[count],(lista->j)[count]);
    }
}


int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    // compare the values of two case of array pointed by i of type int
    return *(int*)a-*(int*)b;
}


void sort(struct element *list)
{
  // we will sort the array pointed by i which contains K elements
  // of type int and size sizeof(int) by using the compare function
    qsort(list->i, K , sizeof(int), compare);
}
```

I realized that compiling it with `gcc` command from terminal gives correct output but using the codeblocks v13.12 which uses the same internal GNU GCC compiler gives wrong output !!

The output of `gcc` command: `gcc -g -Wall main.c -o exec`

gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

```
--------- i ---  j  ---------

row= 1 :   8      8
row= 2 :  29     29
row= 3 :   9      9
row= 4 :  11     11
row= 5 :  20     20
row= 6 :  21     21
row= 7 :   4      4
row= 8 :  16     16
row= 9 :   9      9
row=10 :   2      2

---------------------------
row= 1 :   2      8
row= 2 :   4     29
row= 3 :   8      9
row= 4 :   9     11
row= 5 :   9     20
row= 6 :  11     21
row= 7 :  16      4
row= 8 :  20     16
row= 9 :  21      9
row=10 :  29      2
```

the output of codeblocks (**please note the number of the starting row 3**)

```
row= 3 :  20     20
row= 4 :   4      4
row= 5 :  13     13
row= 6 :   8      8
row= 7 :   4      4
row= 8 :   7      7
row= 9 :  21     21
row=10 :  12     12

---------------------------
row= 1 :   4     24
row= 2 :   4     22
row= 3 :   7     20
row= 4 :   8      4
row= 5 :  12     13
row= 6 :  13      8
row= 7 :  20      4
row= 8 :  21      7
row= 9 :  22     21
row=10 :  24     12
```

[image]

So I was wondering what can lead to such behavior ?

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: What are the outputs?

Comment: You are not new around here, why don't you post the expected output, the two observed outputs, etc.?

Comment: okay ! I will edited it right now !

Comment: Could it be the rand()?

Comment: Please ensure that compilers being used are exactly the same as well as all the flags used during compilation and linking.

Comment: it is the same command used in codeblocks `gcc -Wall -g`

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out the code in my Code::Blocks (Windows 8, Code::Blocks 13.12, GCC 4.7.1), it writes the output properly! It may be, that your terminal emulator is cropping the program output (or something along these lines). I would log the output to a file to make sure.

After you have posted the screenshot, I am now sure of this.

Comment: I am getting the same behavior as OP !!

Comment: Then this is a Linux specific Code::Blocks bug (or maybe Ubuntu specific) - I cannot test this right now, in Windows 8 it works fine. I will fire up my own machine after work, and take a look.